# appending select options with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, append

i currently have an empty drop down list that I would like to fill with some data I got from my database using javascript.
I really have no idea how to do this so right now I am trying this.
Javascript with JQuery.

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
  var code$=data[i].String1;
  var desc$=data[i].Code_Description;
  var str$=$('<option value='+code$+'>'+desc$+'</option>');
  option$.append(str$);
  }
   $('#offCode').html(option$);
```

I have also tried

```
$('#offCode').append(option$);
```

but none of this works

Thanks

Comment: We don't know what `option$` and `data` are, so it's pretty tough to answer.

Comment: you are gonna need to post more of your code and HTML

Comment: What kind of variable is option$?

Comment: Do this entirely with php, not js.

Comment: Can't do this with php if the options are added dynamically client-side...

Comment: I've never seen this style of adding $ after the variable name, what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      var code$=data[i].String1;
      var desc$=data[i].Code_Description;
      $('<option value='+code$+'>'+desc$+'</option>').appendTo($('#idOfSelectElement'));
}
```

The above, obviously, relies on the variables being properly retrieved and filled from your ajax/database-call.

Answer (score 0):

`append()` the option elements you're making directly to the `<select>`

You can't tell what `option$` is from the code snippet, but `append` inserts the argument as a child element.  It would appear that you're `append`'ing all the options to an element, then `append`'ing that element to a select, which would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<option value='abc'>Whatever Text</option>").appendTo($('select'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is loosely based off of the information provided within your question.  Some items may not be applicable as the full scope of your code was not disclosed.  As a result, the solution is slightly modified but you should be able to easily modify it to fit your needs.

HTML:

```
<select></select>
<br />
<h1>Your select box options code:</h1>
<div id="code"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data = {"info":[{"String1":"string-value1","Code_Description":"description1"},{"String1":"string-value2","Code_Description":"description2"},{"String1":"string-value3","Code_Description":"description3"},{"String1":"string-value4","Code_Description":"description4"}]};

data = data.info;

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var e = data[i];
    var code = e.String1;   
    var desc = e.Code_Description;   
    var str =('<option value="'+code+'">'+desc+'</option>');
    $("select").append(str); 
} 

$("#code").text($("select").html());
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/nAPDq/